# Selenium clicks on a wrong link

Tags: java, selenium

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOP14.png] I am trying to click the submenus of particular menu after the mouse hover onto it. In all 9 menus are there. Here is the code of it.

```
<div class="main-nav" id="main-nav" xpath="1">
    <ul class="main-nav-gray user details-menu-tab left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="icon-minimizer" id="minimizer-nav"></ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to click on each submenu link of ul[2] but its clicking on first submenu link of ul[4].
Here is the code for which i am trying to click.

```
<ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul">
    <li class="main-nav-img-label" id="admin-nav">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="main-nav-icons"></svg>
        <label> Analytics </label>
        <ul class="nav-items admin-menu-items" style="top: 50px;" id="admin-menu-items">
            <li class="side-nav-titles"></li>
            <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="PartAClaimsAnalysis42" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=82', 2,'PartAClaimsAnalysis', 42,null,'Facility Claims Analysis')">
                <li>
                    **Facility Claims Analysis**
                </li>
            </a>
            <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="PartBPhysicianClaimsAnalysis43" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=84', 2,'PartBPhysicianClaimsAnalysis', 43,null,'Professional Claims Analysis')">
                <li>
                    **Professional Claims Analysis**
                </li>
            </a>
            <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="PartBDMEAnalysis44" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=83', 2,'PartBDMEAnalysis', 44,null,'DME Analysis')">
                <li>
                    **DME Analysis**
                </li>
            </a>
            <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="PartDPharmacyAnalysis45" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=85', 2,'PartDPharmacyAnalysis', 45,null,'Pharmacy Claims Analysis')"></a>
            <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="SNF Analysis53" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId=93', 2,'SNF Analysis', 53,null,'SNF Analysis')"></a>
        <li class="no-borders"></li>
        <ul class="child-nav-level-2-list"></ul>
        <ul class="child-nav-level-2-list"></ul>
        <ul class="child-nav-level-2-list"></ul>

</li>
</ul>
```

Trying to click on 'Facility Claims Analysis', 'Professional Claims Analysis', DME Analysis etc
But everytime its clicking on a particular link but then page get displayed of 1st submenu that is 'Patient Search' of ul[4].
Here is the code for it:

```
<div class="main-nav" id="main-nav" style="" xpath="1">
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border user-details-menu-tab left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
    <ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul">
        <li class="main-nav-img-label" id="admin-nav">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="main-nav-icons"></svg>
            <label> Care Management </label>
            <ul class="nav-items admin-menu-items" style="top: 168px;" id="admin-menu-items">
                <li class="side-nav-titles"></li>
                    <a class="module-item-child user-default-module selected-nav-item" href="#" id="PatientSearch79" onclick="loadModule('CareManagement/PatientDashboard', 4,'PatientSearch', 79,null,'Patient Search')">
                        <li>
                            Patient Search
                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="PatientCohorts80" onclick="loadModule('CohortPatientEnrollment/Index', 4,'PatientCohorts', 80,null,'Patient Cohorts')"></a>
                    <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="SupervisorHome81" onclick="loadModule('CareManagement/SupervisorHome', 4,'SupervisorHome', 81,null,'Supervisor Home')"></a>
                    <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="CareManagerRoster82" onclick="loadModule('CareManagerRoster/Index', 4,'CareManagerRoster', 82,null,'My Roster')"></a>
                    <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="CareManagementReports91" onclick="loadModule('Reports/Index?settingParameter=CareManagementReportFolder', 4,'CareManagementReports', 91,null,'Reports')"></a>
                    <a class="module-item-child " href="#" id="CMProductivity172" onclick="loadModule('Analytics/Index?dashboardUrlId= 98', 4,'CMProductivity', 172,null,'Care Mgmt Productivity')"></a>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
<ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
<ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
<ul class="main-nav-gray-border menu-items-main-menu-list left-nav-main-menu-container left-nav-img-ul"></ul>
<ul class="icon-minimizer" id="minimizer-nav"></ul>
</div>
```

What i tried so far is

```
 public void hoverTest() throws Exception
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);

`try` {

        for(int h=0; h<3; h++) {
        act.moveToElement(mouseHover).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        act.moveToElement(btnFacilityClaimAnalysis).click().build().perform();
        break;}

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            act.moveToElement(mouseHover).build().perform();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        act.moveToElement(btnFacilityClaimAnalysis).click().build().perform();
        }
```

Also tried with `JavascriptExecutor`, just `click()` method, `.sendKeys(KEYS.ENTER)`. But everytime its clicking expected link(Sometime the control passes to next link as well)  but at last the page 'Patient Search' get displayed.
WebElement:

```
 @FindBy(id="PartAClaimsAnalysis42")
            WebElement btnFacilityClaimAnalysis;
```

OR

```
WebElement btnFacilityClaimAnalysis = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-nav']/ul[2]/li/ul/a[@id='PartAClaimsAnalysis42']")));
```

Comment: I would simplify that XPATH to just "//a[@id='PartAClaimsAnalysis42']"  ids are unique. (or at least they should be... if not the webmasters should fix it.)  Then just use .click() method on the element.  The click method will fire all the events you need: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-click

Comment: @pcalkins, i tried what you suggested but out of 5 times  only once it displayed the expected page and other time same 'Patient Search' page has been displayed.

Comment: probably due do that loop.  Currently you are clicking 3 times without a webdriverwait which seems like it would throw a stale element exception.  Try/catch the click action to see if any exceptions are thrown.

Comment: I removed loop and tried  but didn't work. public void hoverTest() throws Exception
 {
  try{
   Thread.sleep(1500);
   act.moveToElement(mouseHover).build().perform();
   Thread.sleep(3000);
   //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()= 'Quality Ranking']")).click();
   //btnQualityRanking.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
   btnQualityRanking.click();
   } catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

Comment: code's changing a bit there... I would avoid doing that until you understand what's wrong. 
 You want to isolate variables not create more...  what was the exception?

Comment: It has not thrown any exception, Same 'Patient Search' page got displayed.

Comment: Is it possible to click your way through these menus or does the first one only open on a "hover" action?

Comment: First one only hover action, I just added the image, Analytics module contain 18 submenus, but mostly all submens clicking the first submenu  'Patient Search' from Care Mangement module. Please see the image.

Comment: assuming that the menu isn't collapsing, just use a different webdriverwait/click method for each step.  I'd axe the loop.

Comment: You mean expected condition different?  Actually its clicking on right link, while processing it shows the expected page name and when its time to display it displays the 'Patient Search' page.

Comment: I guess what you have to figure out is why 1 out of 5 times it does something different... that seems like a timing issue of some sort.  Can you reproduce the behavior manually? (my guess is a collapsing menu on that hover...)

Comment: Mmanually its working fine, if i debug that time also it works fine, Even while running the script once it displays the Patient Search page and after that if i manually select required page and click then it continue from there and execute all the following steps and script ends successfully.